# Remove words in a text and ignore white spaces

Tags: string, scala, replace

I have a string that may contain multiple words separated by spaces let's call it a stop word, now I have the main string that I want to delete the stop word from, but without taking into consideration white spaces, for example:

```
stopWord = "a wx.yz"
text = "some text a wx.  yz extra ..."
```

The result after applying the right regex should be "some text  extra ...", because regex should treat "a wx.yz" and "a wx.  yz" as same string and not care about spaces in between.

What I did is to remove spaces from both strings and then remove the stopword in the text using:

```
text.replaceAll(stopWord, ""),
```

However, this will lead to a text without spaces and this is not what I want.

I'm using scala but a solution in any language is ok for me.

Comment: So basically, what you call a stop word is a sequence that can have spaces in between the elements?

Comment: @cronoik yes exactly, also the text can also have spaces between it's elements and not the stop word like in the example

Comment: @svg_af_2, 1) what's the programming language used? 2) Should it also replace in text like `"some text a w  x   .  y   z extra ..."` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm using scala but any solution with any programming language is ok for me as I mentioned in the post 2) yes it should, any extra spaces should be ignored from both strings

Answer (score 2):

For a regular expression to solve your problem, you can use your `stopword` string, but you need to handle the whitespaces that can occur between the characters of your stopWord. You can do that with `\s*` which matches any whitespace character zero or infinite times. The full regular expression will be:

```
a\s*w\s*x\s*\.\s*y\s*z
```

Please note that I escaped the `.` and that it doesn't handle whitespace before or after your `stopword`.
To generate that regex in your program, you should do the following:

1. Remove whitespace from stopword
2. Escape regex metacharacters
3. Add `\s*` between every character of `stopword`